# React Native - Debug build displays 'Welcome to React Native' screen instead of home screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

My Application is working fine with the release build, but If I use the debug build, it always shows 'Welcome to React Native' screen when I start my Application & it is not proceeding further. I am not sure how to get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: Try clearing your bundler cache, `react-native start --reset-cache` or the command mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root project folder/directory and then run this:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```